# Intel XDK project + Bootstrap framework + listview not scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, listview, intel-xdk

I have a bootstrap project in Intel XDK (version 1995) with a footer (inside it a grouped buttons) and some subpages, where in one of that pages, I have a listview, which is used to presents a list os banks.

This listview is inside a row. I have already tried to use the listview inside a column, or without a row and column. In all cases, both has the same problem with the listview, that is : my listview do not scrolls !!!

I use a webservice to get my data to load the listview. I am using an ajax jquery, like the code below:

```
    /* button  #btn_bancos */
    $(document).on("click", "#btn_bancos", function(evt)
    {
        var webMethod1 = "http://my_webservice_address";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "XML",
            url: webMethod1,
            success: parseXMLBancos
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            myAppProcessing.hideProcessing();
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });

function parseXMLBancos(xmlBancos)
{
    // Limpa a linha de template original do listview
    $("#lst_bancos").empty();

    // Percorre todas as ocorrências retornadas pelo serviço
    $(xmlBancos).find("Bancos").each(function() {
        var codigo = $(this).find('CdBanco').text();
        var sigla = $(this).find('SgBancoComCodigo').text();

        var banco = '<a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading">' + codigo + '</h4><p class="list-group-item-text">' + sigla +'</p></a>';
        $("#lst_bancos").append(banco);
    });
    activate_subpage("#bancos");
    myAppProcessing.hideProcessing();
}
```

Below is my intex.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Blank App Designer Cordova Web App Project Template</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <style>
            @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
        </style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
        <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
        <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe-hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/sidebar.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/ad/bs_subpage.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#btn_bancos").click(function () {
                  myAppProcessing.showProcessing();
              });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/appdesigner/js/rest-of-space.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="upage" id="mainpage">
            <div class="upage-outer">
                <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col" id="home">
                    <div class="widget uib_w_7 scale-image d-margins logotipo" data-uib="media/img" data-ver="0">
                        <figure class="figure-align">
                            <img src="images/logotipo-home.png">
                            <figcaption data-position="bottom"></figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="uib-footer uib-footer-fixed footer-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_2" data-uib="layout/footer" data-ver="0">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered">
                        <div class="btn-group uib-bs-flex widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button_group" data-ver="1">
                            <button class="btn widget uib_w_4 btn-info" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btn_home"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home button-icon-top" data-position="top"></i>Home</button>
                            <button class="btn widget uib_w_5 btn-info" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btn_consultas"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search button-icon-top" data-position="top"></i>Consultas</button>
                            <button class="btn widget uib_w_6 btn-info" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btn_sair"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left button-icon-top" data-position="top"></i>Sair</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="upage-content hidden vertical-col" id="consultas">
                <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 row-height-1" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                            <span class="widget uib_w_8 d-margins label label-primary" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/badge_and_label" data-ver="1">Consultas</span>
                            <button class="btn widget uib_w_9 d-margins btn-lg btn-info" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btn_bancos"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search button-icon-left" data-position="left"></i>Bancos</button><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="bancos" class="upage-content hidden vertical-col">

                <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_2 row-height-2" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="col uib_col_4 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                            <div class="list-group widget uib_w_10 d-margins rest-of-height" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1" id="lst_bancos">
                                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_11" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading</h4>
                                    <p class="list-group-item-text">List item</p>
                                </a>
                                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_12" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading</h4>
                                    <p class="list-group-item-text">List item</p>
                                </a>
                                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_13" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading</h4>
                                    <p class="list-group-item-text">List item</p>
                                </a>
                            </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app works fine in the emulator, and I can scroll the listview fine. But when I try to use my app in App Preview or directly in my smartphone, the listview do not scrolls. It is loaded correctly, but I can not scrolls it. It seems to be locked. I only see the listitens that is possible to see in the screen. The rest is not accessible, cause the scroll do not works.

But If I change my project to use a PAGE instead of a SUBPAGE, it works. I really need to use a subpage, because I wanna use the same footer navigation menu, with all pages.

What am I doing wrong ? Or is it a bug ?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Hammer.js is being loaded. I have the same issue and couldn't figure a solution. try it without Hammer.js.